# webview error in second activity

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I have created WebView  but in second activity  so when it is starting I have this message net :: err_connection_reset and the app working good but the WebView in second activity not working so help me please in my project
I have created WebView  but in second activity  so when it is starting I have this message net :: err_connection_reset and the app working good but the WebView in second activity not working so help me please in my project
this is my Java class not my main launcher

```
package com.example.abood.readingbooks;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class WebActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
WebView browser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web2);
    browser=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.setWebViewClient(new MyBrowser());
    browser.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
    browser.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
}
public void bugow(View view) {
    EditText txtUrl=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextw);
    browser.loadUrl(txtUrl.getText().toString());
}
public void bunextw(View view) {
    browser.goForward();
}
public void bubackw(View view) {
    browser.goBack();
}
private class MyBrowser extends WebViewClient{
    public boolean shouldOverrideLoadUrlLoading(WebView view,String url){
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;        } }}
```

and this is my manifest file

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.abood.readingbooks">



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".WelcomeActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme1">
        >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" />
    <activity android:name=".SearchActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".Web" />

    <activity android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
    </activity>


</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"       />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: post your logcat

Comment: what???not clear